# Create a popup link in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a flash application. I import the text from external .txt file. I want that some of my words in this text be a link while a user click on it, opens a popup window in swf file. not in browser?
A thing like this:[image]

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to do that is [htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) of TextField object.
You just need to wrap your word "wobbles" with < a/ > tag and define a name for event in href attribute.

```
var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.htmlText = "bla bla <a href='event:wobbles'>wobbles</a> bla bla bla"
```

And then define your handler function that opens such window(Sprite):

```
textField.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK,onTextClick)

function onTextClick(e:TextEvent):void 
{
    if(e.text === "wobbles"){
         //open window
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do this while I have imported the text from a external .txt format file?

Comment: It depends of how would you know which word should be "clickable". You can pre-define specific parse function to wrap such words with < a/ > tag